# How to highlight a button in XAML using Triggers?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an ItemsControl control that displays some buttons.
When I click on one of the buttons I have to show some details of the selected resource (bound to the button).

So when the button is clicked I set a property on the ViewModel called SelectedResource.

That's working fine, what I'd like to do is to highlight the button clicked.

I have a ControlTemplate for my button as follows:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ResourceButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
    <Border Name="SelectedButtonBorder"
            CornerRadius="3">
        <Border x:Name="border" 
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
            CornerRadius="3"
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
            SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}">
                <Image Source="{Binding Type.Value, Converter={converter:ResourceTypeToStringConverter}}"></Image>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" 
                              ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
                              Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                              ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" 
                              Focusable="False"  
                              Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                              RecognizesAccessKey="True" 
                              SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedResource}" Value="">
            <Setter TargetName="SelectedButtonBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
            <Setter TargetName="SelectedButtonBorder" Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I've tried the DataTrigger, but I can't bind the value property of the datatrigger.

So, is there a way to do that using only XAML?

**Edit:**

I don't want to compare the SelectedResource to an empty string, I actually don't know what to compare to. I tried to compare one of the properties of the SelectedResource object to the text shown on the button.

Comment: is Selected resource a String , post the cs. code for SelectedResource.

Comment: Didn't you get an error in the Output Window saying something like 'can't find property `SelectedResource` on object ???(maybe `Button`)'?

Comment: Selected is not a string, but it has a string property that I use to show in the content of the button. I tried to compare both but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming each Button's DataContext is a given `Resource`, that binding in the datatrigger is failing.

I would have a bool property `IsSelected` in the `Resource` class. Then your trigger would look like this:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="SelectedButtonBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
    <Setter TargetName="SelectedButtonBorder" Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
</DataTrigger>
```

Of course, you have to handle deselection of items if only one can be selected at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have correctly set the `DataContext` of your view to an instance of your view model, you should be able to access the `SelectedResource` property using a `RelativeSource Binding` like this:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.SelectedResource, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type 
    YourViewsNamespacePrefix:YourUserControl}}}" Value="">
    <Setter TargetName="SelectedButtonBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
    <Setter TargetName="SelectedButtonBorder" Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
</DataTrigger>
```

Using this `Binding`, the Framework will look for a parent of the `Button` of type `YourUserControl` and when it finds that, it will then look at the object set as its `DataContext` and then finally, look for a property named `SelectedResource` in that object.

---

UPDATE >>>

It really doesn't matter what value you use, as long as you use a value. You said *when the button is clicked I set a property on the ViewModel called SelectedResource*. Let's say that you store the `Button.Name` value in `SelectedResource`... then *that* is what you put in the `DataTrigger`. Of course, you'd need to create a slightly different `DataTrigger` for each `Button`:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.SelectedResource, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type 
    YourViewsNamespacePrefix:YourUserControl}}}" Value="Button1">
    ...
</DataTrigger>
...
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.SelectedResource, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type 
    YourViewsNamespacePrefix:YourUserControl}}}" Value="Button8">
    ...
</DataTrigger>
```

The problem that you would then have is that you couldn't use an `ItemsControl` to display your `Button` elements.

Comment: I think I didn't make myself clear, so I edited the question. I don't want to compare to an empty string, and that's the problem I don't know what to put on the value property of the datatrigger, because it can't  be a fixed value.

Comment: That doesn't work, because my buttons are created dynamically based on what I have in a database.

Answer (score 0):

Or did you try something like this:

```
<Button>
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedResource}" Value="1">
                            <Setter Property="Background"  Value="Red" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedResource}" Value="2">
                            <Setter Property="Background"  Value="White" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
```